# ffmpeg combine multiple commands to crop, clip then convert to gif

Tags: shell, video, command-line, ffmpeg

I have a mp4 video which I need to perform 3 operations and produce the best/decent quality output.

1. I need to crop the size of the video frames - 250x250.
2. I need to clip the video to a certain duration 157 seconds to 167 seconds let's say.

I am able to perform about 2 together in a single command using:

```
./ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 157 -t 10 -vf crop=250:250:200:100 -strict -2 clipped.mp4
```

3. Next I need to convert this into a gif. I am using the below 2 commands for this:

   ```
   ./ffmpeg -y -i clipped.mp4 -vf fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen palette.png
   ./ffmpeg -i clipped.mp4 -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" output.gif
   ```

**My question is-**

Is there any way to combine all 3 above commands into 1? I am able to use the double ampersand `&&` to run the commands after each other but is there a better way in a single command?

Is there any way to avoid the intermediate temporary files like clipped.mp4 and palette.png? Something which can pipe the output to next command?

Thanks for the responses!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would have been a better fit for video.stackexchange.